# Video streaming in sencha touch 2

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

ok i just had a random thought of an sencha touch 2 application built with phonegap. I am thinking of getting a live stream video into my sencha touch 2 application just wanted to know if it is possible. Can anyone shed some more light on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague....by live stream do you mean something like Ustream? Perhaps it's worth checking out their API here:  http://developer.ustream.tv/docs

I'm sure it would be possible to retrieve JSON back from a request much like it is possible with YouTube and sencha, whereby you could setup models such as user, videoid, thumbnail, etc. Check out the The oreilly sencha demo which calls YouTube to get some inspiration.

What would the purpose of using phonegap be? To package or to access certain native features?